# R program: select columns that contain certain words

Tags: r, dataframe, select, contains

I am looking into a R program that is supposed to select columns that contain certain words. For instance I would like to select all the columns that contain `aa 1`:

```
cols<-c('aa z 1','bb x 1', 'aa x 1', 'cc z 1') 
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 5, nrow = 1)) 
colnames(df)<-cols 
df[1,]<-c(1,3,2,2,4)
```

In this example that would mean that i would like to select column 1 (`aa z 1`) and column 3 (`aa x 1`). Is there a possibility to do that?

Thank you in advance for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
select(df, matches("^aa.*1$"))
```

The regular expression match strings that start with "aa" has any number of characters and ends with "1"

Answer (score 1):

In base R, one would do the following:

```
df[,grepl("^aa.*1$", names(df))]
```

The `^aa.*1$` is a pattern specified using regex. Filter any columns that start with `aa` and end with `1`.

**Output**

```
aa z 1 aa x 1
1      1      2
```